# Get parameter from a given URL (not the calling) in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an URI as a string which I get out of a Json in my Logic App. 
How can I access any of the query items of the uri?

Inside the For Each which loops through the uri string list, i tried the following expression to get the query parameter `filename`, but it did not work:

`items('For_each_2')['queries']['filename']`

This returns 'The template language expression 'items('For_each_2')['queries']['filename']' cannot be evaluated because property 'queries' cannot be selected'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `URI parsing functions` in logic app to query property from URI, suppose you want is [uriQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#uriquery), however it returns the whole after `?`. It will be like below.

[image]

And if you want to query a specific property, you should pass them with the logic app trigger URL. It provides `triggerOutputs()['queries']` property to get the queries, and this will return a json object, it will allow you to query specific parameter.

This is a sample:

```
https://xyz.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/id/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=code&test=123&test2=345
```

Then should be able to use `triggerOutputs()['queries']['test']` to query.

[image]

Comment: Thank you George. This is actually the method I tried, but I am not using `triggerOutput` but a string that's coming from the request body json. With that string, it does not work like this (as I described above).

Comment: @gridr, I mean bind the parameter to trigger url to query, if don't you could only use `uriQuery`  get the whole after `?` like my first picture.

Comment: @gridr, cause the string doesn't support your way to query a parameter, it's for json data and the `triggerOutput ` query is in json format that's why it support to get specific parameter.

Comment: @gridr, could you query parameter now? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.